# Access to component functions of gam in mgcv

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Are there ways to access the component functions of a generalised additive model (GAM) fitted using the mgcv library?

Say I fit a gam as follows

```
library(mgcv)

md = gam(y ~ ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1,x2))
```

For further analysis, I would like to evaluate each of the components `ti(x1)`, `ti(x2)` and `ti(x1,x2)` separately, on their own. I know it is possible in principle, since for example `plot.gam` can plot each component separately. But I could find no indication in the help-files how to access those components. Did I overlook something, or is my only way forward, parsing the sources for plot.gam?

**EDIT**

"Access" means that I am able to mimic `predict` for each component. That means, if my model looks like
$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x)$$ then I would like to calculate $f_i(x)$ on its own for any suitable input $x$. This would include the case that single $f_i$ are multivariate tensors, i.e. they look like $f_i= ti(x_1, \ldots, x_d).$

In addition, it would be great if I could also evaluate the gradients $\nabla f_i$ analytically, i.e. without recourse to numeric approximation of the derivatives.

Comment: What sort of access are you looking for? How do you want to use them?

Comment: @GregorThomas See my edit, I would like to be able to evaluate each component.

Comment: `predict()` does *many* things with a GAM, which one do you want specifically? Do you mean you want to evaluate the estimated smooth functions themselves, or the raw basis functions?

Comment: I don't think estimating the derivatives analytically is possible (easily) in general for smooths in mgcv, unless you want to write out the requisite math yourself. You might be able to do it with the *numDeriv* package but you'll need some good knowledge of how mgcv stores its objects to do that I think

Comment: If the finite differences don't work, I may (have to) start digging. But I agree, this requires detailed knowledge of all basis functions and how they are applied within mgcv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm biased, of course, but if you don't mind using tidyverse oriented tools, then my *gratia* package makes doing everything you want pretty simple.

Here's an example

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")

df <- data_sim("eg1", seed = 42)

m <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = df, method = "REML")
```

We can now evaluate the estimated smooth functions at specified values of the covariates. If you don't specify the values, evenly spaced values over the range of each covariate will be generated for you

```r
sm <- smooth_estimates(m)
```

This `sm` is a tibble, where `est` is the estimated function at the specified (or generated) values of the covariate(s), as indicated in the other columns

```
> sm
# A tibble: 400 × 9
   smooth type  by       est    se       x0    x1    x2    x3
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -1.32  0.390 0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 2 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -1.24  0.365 0.0103      NA    NA    NA
 3 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -1.17  0.340 0.0204      NA    NA    NA
 4 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -1.09  0.318 0.0304      NA    NA    NA
 5 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -1.02  0.297 0.0405      NA    NA    NA
 6 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -0.947 0.279 0.0506      NA    NA    NA
 7 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -0.875 0.263 0.0606      NA    NA    NA
 8 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -0.803 0.249 0.0707      NA    NA    NA
 9 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -0.732 0.237 0.0807      NA    NA    NA
10 s(x0)  TPRS  NA    -0.662 0.228 0.0908      NA    NA    NA
# ℹ 390 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

If you want to do this for the observed data, just pass in that data

```r
sm2 <- smooth_estimates(m, data = df)
```

You can plot the estimated functions using the `draw()` method:

```r
sm |> draw()
```

If you want to estimate derivatives of each function on the linear predictor scale (it makes no difference for the model here as it is Gaussian with an identity link function, but it does for non-identify link models) you can use the `derivatives()` function:

```r
fd <- derivatives(m, type = "central")
```

which given the defaults computes first order derivatives via finite differences and a typical frequentist confidence interval:

```
> fd
# A tibble: 400 × 10
   smooth var   by_var fs_var     data derivative    se  crit lower upper
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.000239       7.41  3.33  1.96 0.874  13.9
 2 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0103         7.40  3.33  1.96 0.884  13.9
 3 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0204         7.39  3.30  1.96 0.929  13.8
 4 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0304         7.36  3.24  1.96 1.01   13.7
 5 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0405         7.32  3.15  1.96 1.14   13.5
 6 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0506         7.26  3.04  1.96 1.30   13.2
 7 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0606         7.18  2.90  1.96 1.49   12.9
 8 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0707         7.09  2.76  1.96 1.69   12.5
 9 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0807         6.99  2.61  1.96 1.87   12.1
10 s(x0)  x0    NA     NA     0.0908         6.87  2.47  1.96 2.03   11.7
# ℹ 390 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

see `?gratia::derivatives` for more.

If you want the weighted basis functions, using the `basis()` function

```r
bs <- basis(m)
```

which returns

```
> bs
# A tibble: 3,600 × 9
   smooth type  by_variable bf      value       x0    x1    x2    x3
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>       <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          1     -0.0818 0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 2 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          2      0.699  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 3 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          3     -0.112  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 4 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          4      0.262  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 5 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          5     -0.448  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 6 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          6      0.648  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 7 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          7     -0.326  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 8 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          8     -1.65   0.000239    NA    NA    NA
 9 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          9     -0.308  0.000239    NA    NA    NA
10 s(x0)  TPRS  NA          1     -0.0818 0.0103      NA    NA    NA
# ℹ 3,590 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Yup, looks exactly like what I need! Except for the derivatives ... But I'll give them a try, maybe finite differences work.